# Why is pip installing packages in the current directory instead of the standard site-packages location?

Tags: python, pip

I am using python3.8 and pip3 to attempt to install packages

This is my sample output when I run
`pip3 list -v`

```
Package    Version Location                                                              Installer
---------- ------- --------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------
GDAL       3.1.2   /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
numpy      1.19.1  /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
pip        20.1.1  /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
protobuf   3.13.0  /usr/local/Cellar/protobuf/3.13.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages
PyQt5      5.15.0  /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages                                pip
PyQt5-sip  4.19.24 /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages                                pip
setuptools 49.2.0  /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
six        1.15.0  /usr/local/Cellar/protobuf/3.13.0/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages
TBB        0.1     /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
wheel      0.34.2  /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
```

When I run `pip3 install requests`, a folder called `file:` is created in the directory from which I ran the `pip3 install requests` command. Deep down in this newly created directory are the files installed for the requests package:
`/ExampleDirectory/file:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages`

Why has pip3 installed the package here in the new `file:` folder instead of the standard location of
`/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages`  ?

How can I get pip3 to install the file for the requests package here: `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages` ?

Comment: Feels like a bug to me, where one part of the code is creating the URL `file:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages` to specify where to install to, but then another part of the code is treating that URL like a filesystem path, and since it doesn't start with '/', interprets it as a relative path from the current directory, with `file:` being the first level directory name. - could also be a config issue possibly, if it happens that you've mucked with the system at all.

Comment: Do you have an activated virtual environment? Try "which python" or "which pip", or "env | grep VIRTUAL_ENV"

Comment: @Steve I have defintely mucked with the system in that I attempted to delete all my versions of Python, then downloaded Python 3.8.5.

Comment: @KennyOstrom I do not have a virtual environment activated. I find that the issue is still present when I try the above after activating a virtual environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve this by changing the pip config as suggested by Steve.
Running the command 
`pip3 config list` 
gives 
`global.target='file:///Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages'`

Then running the command
`pip3 config --editor nano edit`
lets you change global.target to your desired location